# jQuery DataTables fnReloadAjax - How to pass new POST parameters on reload?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, datatables

I want to be able to reload my datatable with AJAX, but need to be able to pass POST parameters.

**Here is how I initialize the table passing custom properties via POST (*using aoData*):**

```
oTable = jQuery('#searchresults').dataTable({
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
"sAjaxSource": "ajax/index-ajax.cgi",  
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "clientID", "value":jQuery("#clientID").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "username", "value":jQuery("#username").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "company", "value":jQuery("#company").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "email", "value":jQuery("#email").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "region", "value":jQuery("#region").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "role", "value":jQuery("#role").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "hrTitle", "value":jQuery("#hrTitle").val() } );
    aoData.push( { "name": "searchType", "value":jQuery("#searchType").val() } );
}
});
```

**Here is how I reload the AJAX source:**

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

**How can I pass new/updated parameters into the fnReloadAjax call?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for my case I actually don't have to do anything. The 'fnServerParams' is already being set to grab the values for my custom arguments from the inputs (i.e. jQuery("#clientID").val()). Basically, it carries over from the datatable init.

When oTable.fnReloadAjax() is called, it still uses the custom 'fnServerParams'. Fortunately, I don't need to add any new arguments, but if you did then I think you would just have to update the 'fnServerParams' object on your datatable object prior to calling fnReloadAjax().